# How to surpass Context Menu & MultiSelectModel 100 files limit?

Tags: c#, wpf, shell, contextmenu

### Explanation:

I've noticed that my program can only open a max of 100 files from the context menu, more than that it will only open the first one. So I've been doing research and I found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers) which has this explanation:

[image: COM | LEGACY]

Here is what my program does to create a shell command:

```
RegistryKey farFile = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Classes\*\shell\MyProgram");

farFile.SetValue("", "Open with MyProgram");
farFile.SetValue("Icon", AppPath);
farFile.SetValue("MultiSelectModel", "Player");
farFile.CreateSubKey("command").SetValue("", "\"" + AppPath + "\" \"%1\" ");
```

### Question:

What can be done so my program can surpass this player limit? Do I transform my shell command to COM, and how?

Comment: Actually you have answered your own question, now as on how itself is a huge topic. Here's a (discouraged) way to write COM extensions in C#: https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell